# same transition-duration works differently on elements

Tags: css

I bumped into problem with transition duration. Somehow even if I set same duration for all elements, some elements are taking to much time when applying transition. The code in `globals.scss` file is:

```css
:root {
  --transition-property: all;
  --transition-duration: 0.3s;
  --transition-function: ease;
}

* {
  transition: var(--transition-property) var(--transition-duration)
    var(--transition-function);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

For exampe, my `Header.component.tsx` file where I use button with icon it it, has this code:

```
<div className={styles.buttonsContainer}>
   <Button
   icon={IconsEnum.exit}
   iconPosition='right'
   variant={ButtonVariantEnum.primary}
   size='sm'
   onClick={handleLogoutClick}
   text='Logout'
   />
   <SwitchThemeButton />
</div>
```

```
.buttonsContainer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10px;
  stroke: white;
}
```

My `button` component return this jsx

```
return (
  <button
    className={buttonClass}
    disabled={disabled}
    onClick={isClickUnavailable ? () => null : onClick}
    style={style}
    type={type}
    id={id}
    {...props}
  >
    <div className={styles.loader}>
      <SvgIcon src={IconsEnum.loader} size={30} />
    </div>
    {icon && <SvgIcon src={icon} size={20} />}
    {text && <Text size={textSizeMap[size]}>{text}</Text>}
  </button>
  );
```

```
.button {
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: inline-flex;
  gap: 10px;
  min-height: inherit;
  border-radius: 6px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
  color: black;
  stroke: black;

  &_variant {
    &_primary {
      border: 2px solid var(--white);
      background: var(--light-primary);
      color: var(--white);
      stroke: var(--white);

      &:hover {
        background: var(--white);
        stroke: var(--light-primary);
        color: var(--light-primary);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Nowhere in css files for these components I change transition duration.
As you can see in this video, my SVG icons are taking way more time to transition than the button background and button text color. Even in dev tools, there are no other styles that prevent my root transitions.

https://youtu.be/0c2qeJ6KR-M

Comment: Please put enough code into your question to show the problem - we can’t debug a video.

Comment: @AHaworth thank you for the comment, I have added my header code where I use buttons and button component tsx

Comment: you are using * for setting transition on all the page. this looks wrong. maybe an element is transitioning along with its parent to you see a double speed transition?

Comment: Im using this type of css selection in all projects I have, but only in this one I found a problem with transition duration on different items

Comment: try creating a '.my-transition' class which you will add to any element you want to have transition instead of all elements. maybe you can isolate the problem this way. and it's a better practice to save resources. also `div` inside `button` doesn't help try `span`